# Get object from another model for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method in a class and I need to pull an item from another model to use in this method. I cant seem to pull the item because I am using current_user to get the other item and the model does not recognize current_user. I am not sure how DRY this is anyway because I have read that the model should not call current_user. Here is the method...

```
class Upsell
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :charges

...

  def total_fees
    items = []
    items << (current_user.reportapprovals.first.admin_request_report_type).to_i
      if self.multiple_admin == true
       items << self.multiple_admin_amount
      end
end
```

My error is that

```
undefined local variable or method `current_tenant' for #<Upsell:0xc82c9d39>
```

I am wondering if I should set user in the model but so far that has not worked.

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: If you have the **User** related to **Upsell** then you can call `self.user` instead of **current_user** else you have to pass it as a parameter to the function. And you will never get params inside your model so this --> `User.find(params[:id])` line doesn't work.

Comment: Normally, current_user is helper method stored in application_controller and it's not accessible from any Model. Maybe you could use `self.user.reportapprovals...` insted of `current_user.reportapprovals...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `current_user` as function parameter

```
def total_fees_for user
    items = []
    items << (user.reportapprovals.first.admin_request_report_type).to_i
    if self.multiple_admin == true
       items << self.multiple_admin_amount
    end
end
```

Comment: Wow, that was it! I actually made it more difficult than it was.